# What would happen to my ETH token if I transfer it from Binance using BEP20 network to Eth main network in Metamask?

Tags: metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, wallet-transfer, binance-smart-chain, mycrypto

Recently, I transferred **Eth** from Binance using **BEP20 network** instead of using ERC20 to Eth main net in metamask. And i also **received** it in my BNB Smart chain as Bnb pegged Eth.
But soon after receiving it, all my eth got **automatically transferred** to **unknown** wallet address. And when I checked it in **BNB Scan** , i saw there a strange transaction.
Surprisingly, it was the **same wallet address** (0xD58F912917f2fa9BeE548790e3B42CC919BF4E34) through which i received the Eth from my Bnb app wallet in Bnb smart chain while transfering.
So, please tell me how can i get all my Eth back. **What should i do now?**

[image]

Comment: Not a Binance pro, but seems to be something you should figure out with Binance, not here.

Comment: You should share more details, like you account and the transaction where you received. If your address starts with `0xD58F91291..` then the ETH as an ERC20 token remains in that account.